# retrieve nested attributes in model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get a few attributes in my model.

I define my reportUrl model like this:

```
    var ReportUrl = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/report/test/'
});
```

then in my view, I fetch it like this, and add it to my test model. Note - it only fetches one URL for each test:

```
            var reportUrl = new ReportUrl({ id: test.id });
            reportUrl.fetch();
            test.set({
                reportUrl: reportUrl
            });
                var view = new reportUrlView({
                    model: test
                });
```

If I write it out, I can see it in my browser console(see the screenshot below).  I just can't figure out how to access the data I need.

I need to get the serverUrl and reportExt attributes.

So I define 'this.reportUrl' like this:
this.reportUrl = this.model.get('reportUrl');

if I do

```
console.log('this.reportUrl:', this.reportUrl);
```

I see this screen:
[image]

But I've failed at all my attempts to get the attributes I need:

```
this.reportUrl.get('serverUrl') = undefined
this.reportUrl.serverUrl = undefined

this.model.attributes.reportUrl.get('serverUrl') = undefined
this.model.attributes.reportUrl.serverUrl = undefined
this.model.attributes.reportUrl.attributes.serverUrl = undfined
```

this is the only line that produced anything:

`this.model.attributes.reportUrl.attributes = id: xxxxxx ^^ the test.id above` when I called new ReportUrl.

So is there anyway to access these attributes?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `this` in your code..? where does it execute..? What is `test`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your major issue is that `fetch()` is executed asynchronously.

what you see in console is the data after the request is complete, but your code executes before, hence returning `undefined`.

Your code should be

```
var reportUrl = new ReportUrl({ id: test.id });
reportUrl.fetch({
    success:function(model,response){
      test.set({
         reportUrl: model
      });
      var view = new reportUrlView({
         model: test
      });
   }
});
```

or

```
var reportUrl = new ReportUrl({ id: test.id });
reportUrl.fetch().then(function(){
  test.set({
     reportUrl: reportUrl
  });
  var view = new reportUrlView({
     model: test
  });
});
```

Not sure why you're setting a model into another - It looks like all you need is to do `test.fetch()`, and your backend shold return an object `reportUrl` with the required data in response. That'll be much cleaner.

anyway you can access the attributes like `this.model.get('reportUrl').get('serverUrl')` , assuming `this` points to your view.

`this.model.attributes.reportUrl.attributes.serverUrl`, `this.model.get('reportUrl').attributes.serverUrl`, `this.model.attributes.reportUrl.get('serverUrl')` etc should also work, but that's not the backbone way of doing it.

Comment: thanks.  ReportUrl is not an attribute of the 'test' model so that's why I was adding reportUrl as an attribute of test.